# In MySQL I want to bring private posts if they are my friends and all public posts

Tags: mysql

could someone help me please?
I want to bring the publications of a user by their id, bring the private ones if they are my friends and all the public publications
I have the following tables.
Users:

| id_user | email | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brayan | ... |
| 2 | Berenice | ... |
| 3 | Joe | ... |

Friends:

| id_friend | id_user(is FK to users) | id_user_2(is FK to users) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

and publications:

| id_publication | id_user(is FK to users) | message | is_public |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | I am happy today | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | This is public | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | This is not public | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | I am happy today | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in my solution i assumed id_user_2 column is your friend user id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM publications 
WHERE is_public = 0 AND 
(id_user IN (SELECT id_user_2 FROM friends WHERE id_user = 1) OR id_user IN (SELECT id_user FROM friends WHERE id_user_2 = 1)) OR 
id_user = 1;
```

Hope you find this solution helpful.

Comment: Thanks, It worked correctly for me, just I changed the first and for an or.

Comment: Come back, it doesn't work for me at all :c since it doesn't bring me the publications if my friend is in id_user and I in id_friend

Comment: Check it again, i've updated my comment.